# How do I get a value where a drag-able element dropped?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm now developing a website that can drag elements and drop into a table cells (each cell has its "ID")

Now I can drag and drop the element to the cells but I want to know

- How to get the ID of table cell where I dropped the element?

here's the picture's concept.

[image]

Suppose that cell's ID are the combination of row and column number.

Comment: Are you using jQuery or trying to build it on plain JavaScript.

Comment: Show us your code and make a fiddle :)

Comment: @DeepakBiswal I use jQuery draggable and snap function to stick the element to the table cell.

Comment: Check [this](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/) I think this works for you. There is 'drop' method where you have the target element reference.

Comment: @BojanPetkovski here's it http://jsfiddle.net/81ja79Ls/1/ :)

Comment: @DeepakBiswal http://jsfiddle.net/81ja79Ls/1/ I use drop method and set it to print the ID to console but it shows nothing :(

Comment: console.log 'ui' value and see the target element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/81ja79Ls/8/).

Try something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#draggable").draggable({ snap: ".drop"});
    $(".drop").droppable({
        drop: function(event, ui){
         console.log($(this).attr('id'));
    }
  });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

At first you need to rename yours IDs because one ID can't start with a number. You neet at lest one letter, example "ID11" "ID12" ...

Than what are the Cells? div? Td? Input?

Can you a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) ?

-Edit.

you need something like thise:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/81ja79Ls/3/)

you must only change your skript to:

```
$(function() {
    $("#draggable").draggable({ snap: ".drop"});
    $(".drop").droppable({
        drop: function(event, ui){
         console.log("Dropped to" + $(".drop").attr("id"));
            $( this )
            .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
            .find( "p" )
            .html( "Dropped!" );
    }
  });
  });
```

Comment: here's the jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/81ja79Ls/1/

I use <td> as a table cell.

Comment: as @Bojan Petkovski sayed, you can also add "alert($(this).attr("id"));" in the script

Answer (score 0):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ak9hy8je/2/).

First you need to enable the table cells to be dragged to by defining `ondragover` event callback. In the fiddle:

```
box.ondragover = function (evt) { evt.preventDefault(); };
```

`preventDefault` ensures that the browser does not set a dropdown lock on the element.

Then you simply play around with the event data, like this:

```
box.ondrop = function (evt) { droppedTo.innerHTML = evt.toElement.id; };
```

`toElement` holds reference to the element that you drop on, and you can get all the data you need from it, including `id`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your script like this

```
$(function () {
    $("#draggable").draggable({
        snap: ".drop"
    });
    $(".drop").droppable({
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            alert($(this).attr("id"));
            console.log("Dropped to " + $(this).attr("id"));
        }
    });
});
```

Change from **$(".drop").attr("id")** to **$(this).attr("id")** to get the id of the element that you are dropping into :)

Example http://jsfiddle.net/81ja79Ls/4/